# Folder Effective Permissions Not Accurate

Tags: permissions, network-share, directory, ntfs

I have a folder on a Windows Server Standard 2008 that is shared. There is a user that I need to restrict access to this folder. They connect over VPN. When I look at the Effective Permissions, this user has no listed permissions, but when they connect via VPN they can still access this folder and all of its subfolders. The folder is not inheriting parent permissions and the user does not show up in any of those listed having permissions set for the folder. The only group this user is in is Users. Why does this user still have access to this folder?

[image: Effective Permissions image]

Answer (score 0):

So, after further investigation and analyzing VPN sessions, it turns out the the user in question was logged in as the restricted user, but given access privileges of another VPN user that also uses that PC to remotely login. The second user still had access to the restricted folder. So, now I just need to track down why the VPN remote sessions are getting confused.